# No entra a bloque else if

Tags: javascript, condiciones, google-apps-script, else

Estaba realizando un proyecto con Google App Script en conjunto a forms y sheets. En síntesis, el proyecto trata de que al enviar las respuestas a un formulario se dispara una función que dependiendo de la puntuación del formulario es el resultado (siendo la puntuación un entero) el problema es que no entra en el bloque else - if.
¿Hay alguna otra forma óptima de validar un número dentro de un rango de valores?

```
      Logger.log("EMAIL: "+emailTo);
      Logger.log("VALOR: "+valor);
      Logger.log("NOMBRE: "+nombre);
      Logger.log("TELEFONO: "+telefono);

      if(emailTo !== undefined){

        var punt = parseInt(valor);
        Logger.log("PUNTUACION: "+punt);


      else if(punt>=29 && punt>64){

              var resul = " depresión severa";

              Logger.log("LLEGO AQUI! " );

              htmlC.name=nombre;
              htmlC.res= resul;

              Logger.log("HTML AQUI :   " + htmlClient);

              var htmlClient = htmlC.evaluate().getContent();

              MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, "Texto HTML", { htmlBody: htmlClient });

              Logger.log("SEVERA  " +emailTo);

   }
}
```

El resultado del log es

```
[19-11-20 06:35:31:596 PST] EMAIL: example@gmail.com 
[19-11-20 06:35:31:596 PST] VALOR: 60 / 126 
[19-11-20 06:35:31:597 PST] NOMBRE: Juan 
[19-11-20 06:35:31:597 PST] TELEFONO: 26446466846 
[19-11-20 06:35:31:597 PST] PUNTUACION: 60
```

Comment: Bienvenido. En este sitio las preguntas no de deben incluir presentaciones personales, firmas, lemas, etc. que no aporte a la descripción de la situación o problema. Ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behaviour . Tampoco deben incluirse etiquetas en los títulos.

Comment: Cuando se incluye código que no funciona este debe ser un ejemplo mínimo y completo. En el código que has incluido la declaración de la función está incompleta, falta la declaración de las variables y una descripción breve de cómo estás llamando la función.Además los datos sobre la pregunta que has indicado en comentarios a una de las respuestas deberían incluirse en la pregunta.

Comment: No entra en el `else if` aparentemente porque el email es diferente de `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que si lo que quieres es que el numero entre a un rango la condición correcta sería

```
punt>=29 && punt<=64
```

Ahi indica que quieres que abarque desde 29 hasta 64, ya que en tu condición como la tienes entraba cualquier numero desde y mayor de 29.

Answer (score 4):

Estás definiendo `punt` dentro del IF. Si no entra al IF, no hay variable `punt` y no tienes cómo entrar al ELSE.

Edito porque el segundo problema para ejecutar el bloque ELSE está en la comparación lógica. Preguntar si `(punt>=29 && punt>64)` se puede reducir a `punt > 64` y posiblemente tus datos no están en ese intervalo.

Como lo indican en los comentarios, es muy probable que desees revisar los valores mayores o iguales a 29 y estrictamente menores a 64. Si es así, tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
 Logger.log("EMAIL: "+emailTo);
  Logger.log("VALOR: "+valor);
  Logger.log("NOMBRE: "+nombre);
  Logger.log("TELEFONO: "+telefono);

  // moví esto aquí para que SIEMPRE haya variable
  var punt = parseInt(valor); 

  if(emailTo !== undefined) {


    Logger.log("PUNTUACION: "+punt);


  } else if(punt>=29 && punt<64) {

          var resul = " depresión severa";

          Logger.log("LLEGO AQUI! " );

          htmlC.name=nombre;
          htmlC.res= resul;

          Logger.log("HTML AQUI :   " + htmlClient);

          var htmlClient = htmlC.evaluate().getContent();

          MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, "Texto HTML", { htmlBody: htmlClient });

          Logger.log("SEVERA  " +emailTo);

 }
}
```

Comment: realice el cambio y al parecer sigue sin entrar al bloque correspondiente. Deberia aparecer 

[19-11-20 06:35:31:596 PST] LLEGO AQUI! y tambien el HTML en si. 

No entiendo que puede estar sucediendo

Comment: Creo que la condición está mal: `punt>=29 && punt>64` sólo entrará en valores superiores a `64`. ¿Cuál es la condición que se debe cumplir realmente? ¿No debería ser: `punt>=29 && punt<=64`?  para un rango entre `29` y `64`?

Comment: Tenes razon. La condicion a cumplir es que el valor esté entre 29 y 63. Muchas gracias por hacerme ver mi error

Comment: @PabloAraya realmente el error que te senaló Alfabravo en su respuesta era relevante, sin haberlo corregido tu código no funcionaría o funcionaría mal. Lo correcto era que Alfa editase su respuesta señalando el otro error de la comparación y que sea esta la respuesta aceptada. En mi anterior comentario señalé el error por eso, en vez de apresurarme a escribir una respuesta. Creo que esto quita calidad al sitio. Saludos.

Comment: Buen hallazgo, @A.Cedano . Ya mismo edito

Comment: El comentario del OP indica que quiere que sean valores hasta 63

Comment: ¿No falta tambien un '}' antes del 'else if'?

Comment: Hay otras cosas que continúan faltando, por ejemplo, no se han declarado variables, que en el caso de `punt` resulta "indispensable" la declaración de `valor` y en el caso de  `MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, "Texto HTML", { htmlBody: htmlClient });` hace falta la declaración de `emailTo`, `subject` y `htmlC` porque no se puede asignar una propiedad a un `undefined` y `nombre`.

Comment: @PabloAraya Los datos relevantes sobre tu pregunta como el rango de valores, está muy bien que lo menciones en un comentario a una respuesta para notificar al autor de la misma pero además deberían incluirse en la pregunta. Esto porque las preguntas deben ser claras y completas pensando en lectures futuros no sólo en los que actualmente están participando en la conversación además de que "eventualmente" los comentarios podrían ser eliminados.

Comment: @Rubén ese comentario, como cualquier otro que pida información adicional, aclaraciones y demás, va en la pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Cuál de todos? :P

Comment: @Rubén todos los que están acá! :)  Si el ejemplo no es un ejemplo mínimo verificable, el camino es decirle a quien pregunta que se necesitan más datos para sugerir una respuesta. En mi caso, por ejemplo, sugerí un par de cosas porque el OP no dijo "no pasa nada" sino que "no valida tal caso" y eso da a entender que en algún lugar están las cosas inicializadas.

Comment: Lo de decirle al OP que el código en la pregunta debería ser un [mcve] en la pregunta misma está hecho. El mencionar que hay variables que no están declaradas es pertinente mencionarlo acá porque en el el código de la respuesta no están declaradas. Si no quieres declararlas, está bien. Se podría señalar los cambios que debe hacer el OP sin copiar el código completo. Aprovecho para mencionar que en en esta respuesta sería bueno mencionar que en el código del OP le falta el `}` antes del `else`.

Comment: @Rubén Eso es porque no lo consideré relevante a la respuesta y eso ya lo dije en el comentario anterior.